# Alternative to deeply nested function calls or events

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, communication

I have repeatedly come across this problem in multiple projects:
I end up with objects (nested deep down in a structure) that need to communicate with objects external to that structure.

Currently I have the Game class which instantiates the Hud and ObjectsList classes.
The Hud instantiates the various heads up display panels, which themselves instantiate smaller sections containing the visible TextFields.
The ObjectsList instantiates the various game objects, including the Player class.
For the Player to communicate to a specific Hud panel I currently need to trigger a sequence of custom events all the way up to Game, then have game call a method on Hud, which calls the method on the appropriate Hud panel.
Ths seems rather clunky and inefficient.
I could pass Player a reference to the Hud as it could be said that Player 'has-as' Hud. But is that tight coupling? And, given that I'm not expecting to have to reuse this code elsewhere, does that matter?
I could also use the Observer Pattern and register Hud panels to listen for updates from Player, but then, when both Player and hud panel are not immediately accessible to Game, where does this get managed?
Or should all of the instantiations happen in Game and then the structure 'composed'?

I am keen to know if there is something I don't understand that makes these seemingly clunky, nested structures occur, or if they are just a necessary byproduct.
And if there is anything fundamentally wrong with the structure I've suggested, I'd appreciate knowing what the practical alternatives are (preferably in un-jargoned language as I am a self taught coder).
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the player collects some coins, and you need to update something in the HUD to reflect the number of coins.

You cannot escape the fact that this is a specific problem, and this logic won't be completely reusable unless you spend an insane amount of time developing a dynamic gothic solution that will solve all your communication problems and make your breakfast too.

But what you can do, is to decouple this logic as much as you can from your reusable classes (ie: `Player`, `HudLabel`) using a number of different OO patterns (composition, etc).

My **personal subjective solution** to this problem would be to have the base generic logic in the `Player` class, and extend it with a sub class like `CoinGamePlayer` where all the project specific logic resides. Then have a reference to a central communicator class using composition. This would apply also to a `GoldCoinHudLabel` too.

As a side note, take a look a the Signals framework. By far the best event solution for AS3 projects:

https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

http://www.developria.com/2010/10/an-introduction-to-as3-signals.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems like the key part to your answer is 'have a reference to a central communicator class using composition'. Unfortunately, I don't understand quite what this means. When you say 'central' do you mean a singleton? And if not a singleton, how is an instance of this class obtained from deep inside a nested structure? If you could give a more detailed explanation, I'd really appreciate it! Cheers.

Comment: A singleton would be easier to implement, but you could also have an instance in your `Game` class, and pass a reference to that instance.

Comment: Either way, take a look at Signals. It's really worth the time you'll spend learning how it works.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with Events in AS3. I've read the intro-to-signals page and, unless it enables you to 'wire' objects that high level objects don't have direct access to, I don't see the advantage.

Comment: You can wire anything with anything with `EventDispatcher` or `Signals`. What you need is as simple as having a reference to the centralised object (as I already said in my answer). A singleton would make things easier, of course, but it's not required. The advantage of `Signals` is ease of use, quick customisation, and performance.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I'm being obtuse but, irrespective of whether I use EventDispatcher or Signals, how do I avoid the deeply nested, repeated functions or nested event dispatches to and from an object? Even for the reference to the CentralCommunicator class to be passed, I would need functions all the way down to the new object. Is that OK or is there some way of avoiding that? Thanks.

Comment: One solution would be using a `Singleton`. Another, depending on what you are trying to achieve, is using a class with `static` methods and vars.